# ScrollView undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a ScrollView and referencing it using ref but when I'm calling `scrollTo` of it, I am getting `undefined is not an object`.

```
next = () => {
 this.scrollView.scrollTo({x:0, y:0, animated: true});
} 

render() {
 return(
  <View>
   <ScrollView ref={component => { this.scrollView = component }}>
    <View></View>
    <View></View>
    <View></View>
   </ScrollView>
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.next()}>
    <Text>Next</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
 )
}
```

The remedies that I have tried but never worked includes

- using `.bind(this)` when calling the function
- `.bind(this)` in the constructor
- using refs `ref='scrollView'` and `this.refs.scrollView`
- using arrow functions

Am I missing something here?

Comment: your code seems to work: https://snack.expo.io/SkqqKplBH

Comment: did you define `this.scrollView = null` in your constructor?

Comment: Did you forget importing scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
next = () => {
 this.scrollView.scrollTo({x:0, y:0, animated: true});
} 

render() {
 return(
  <View>
   <ScrollView ref={component => { this.scrollView = component }}>
    <View></View>
    <View></View>
    <View></View>
   </ScrollView>
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.next}>
    <Text>Next</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
 )
}
```

we need only one side binding.